# Can't find .NET Framework 4.7 targeting pack in Visual Studio Installer on Windows Server 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7

We have a Windows Server 2016, with a build agent for TFS 2017 update 1, which is using Visual Studio Entreprise 2017.

- All windows updates are done
- I installed the .NET 4.7 Runtime and the .NET 4.7 Targeting Pack (I tried online and offline)

  - the key in registery exists (see screenshot)
  - this folder is present C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7
- I relaunched Visual Studio Installer
- I reinstalled Visual Studio
- I rebooted a bunch of times

But I still can't see the .NET Framework 4.7 SDK or targeting pack in Visual Studio Installer > individual Components.

- [installation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whCPm.jpg)

A working short term solution, to add this param the Build solution Step

> /p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7"

Does anyone have any ideas how to force .NET 4.7 to be detected by the Visual Studio Installer?

Comment: The installer doesn't know beans about 4.7 and surely never will until it gets updated.  Might happen some day.  It is not clear at all why this matters.  All that the targeting pack does is provide you with the option to select 4.7 as the target framework in your project.  Project > Properties > Application tab > Target framework combobox.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm writing a small guide for installing VS 2017, and I also don't see this option (Windows 7).

Comment: Why do you want Visual Studio Installer to detect something newer than itself? Microsoft might update the bits to support .NET 4.7, but that's obviously not something mandate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem on Windows Server 2016 with latest Visual Studio 2017.

Solved it by installing: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168.

(Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 Developer Pack and Language Packs for Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 Anniversary Update, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2016 combo package).

Answer (score 3):

**Install Developer Pack** of the required .NET Framework to make it visible and selectable in Visual Studio.

For example .NET Framework 4.7.1 was not visible for me in Visual Studio 2017 (Although it was installed on my  machine), So what I did that installed developer pack for 4.7.1 and it worked like a magic.